# Prevent WP from escaping html on edit posts screen

Tags: php, functions, core-modifications

In `/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table` there's a snippet of code that strips html from excerpts on the edit posts screen:

```
echo '<span class="protected-post-excerpt">' . esc_html( get_the_excerpt() ) . '</span>';> } else { esc_html( get_the_excerpt();}
```

I have found that I can get the html to show by editing the core file to this:

```
echo '<span class="protected-post-excerpt">' . esc_html( get_the_excerpt() ) . '</span>';> } else { get_the_excerpt();}
```

However, I know that editing core files is verboten, so I tried adapting [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151161/how-to-prevent-wordpress-from-stripping-html-tags-in-excerpt) by adding this to `functions.php`:

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'esc_html');
```

but it didn't work.

Since I want to allow all tags, it doesn't seem necessary to add `wpse_allowedtags()` as explained in the same post.

What am I missing?

This is what WP does:

[image: Tags stripped]

This is what I'm after:

[image: Tags not stripped]

Comment: You can't remove the escaping with `remove_filter` because it isn't applied with `add_filter`. The escaping is there for a reason. If the HTML in the excerpt is malformed, it can break the entire page.

Comment: what problem does showing the tags solve? Noting that the code you shared before and after snippets of technically doesn't show an excerpt in either case as there is no `echo` statement, and you can't use `remove_filter` to undo an `esc_html` like that, function calls are a PHP language feature, filters are a WordPress feature implemented in PHP code. In the answer you linked to they can use remove filter because somewhere else in the code is an `add_filter` call thats being undone by the answer. If you explain why you're trying to do this though then there are other better solutions

Comment: I use a lot of html in my snippets, including an image. It's very difficult to work with the list of posts when the exerpts are full of code. I've added screenshots (from 2 different sites) to show the difference. Please do not recommend using featured images instead.

Comment: I see you specifically mentioned featured images, but there are other solutions too. Image tags will get used in lots of places where HTML tags are very very bad, e.g. search engine results and social media. If you were doing this to put images in the excerpts on post listings then there are ways of doing that which are far better than inserting image tags directly into excerpts, and featured images is not the only way to do that. You could easily have a field to add an image then a filter to insert it dynamically. What's the original purpose of the HTML tags in the excerpt?

Comment: It looks like you had a problem and devised the solution of putting images in the excerpts, but now you're trying to fix your solution. It would be much much easier to solve the original problem, as well as the SEO and security problems with what you did. Otherwise if we stick strictly to your question then there's a straight forward answer to the question you asked, and it's very bad news, but it doesn't have to be. Looking at your site, the obvious answer of use a featured image makes sense, but it looks like there's a reason you've not shared that prevents you from doing that?

Comment: Basically this is due to the theme I chose when I started my first blog 9 years ago, and now use for half a dozen others. It's simply impossible, at this point, to spend the time it would take to find a new theme and republish thousands of posts. I haven't had any problems with regard to search engines and social media - my posts get indexed and published without issue. So yes, I'm trying to fix my solution, because the real solution (new theme, republishing) would take forever or a ton of money.

Comment: "What's the original purpose of the HTML tags in the excerpt?" Having the snippet wrap around the image on archive pages, as show in the second screenshot.